# Find and insert a value from previous row based on a match between dimensions into the same SQL database table

Tags: sql

Is it possible to get 'Dimension 3' values from Group 'Extension' into rows where Group is 'Finishing' and 'Primer'?
The problem is that the program sending the data into SQL does not give 'Dimension3' values for Groups 'Finishing' and 'Primer'.
Database table **[3E_IDB_Aru].dbo.Material** structure looks like this:

| ID | P_GUID | Area | Group | Code | Variant | Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Dimension3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Extension | 27/1 ver | sj | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 55 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9005 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 56 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9010 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 57 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | GW201 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 0 |
| 58 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | ZW-400 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 0 |
| 59 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Extension | 27/1 ver | sj | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 60 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9005 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 61 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9010 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 62 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | GW201 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 0 |
| 63 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | ZW-400 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 0 |
| 64 | 519AEC | 0,0296 | Extension | 27/1 top | sj | 1480 | 20 | 110 |
| 65 | 519AEC | 0,0296 | Finishing | RAL 9005 | (kein) | 1480 | 20 | 0 |
| 66 | 519AEC | 0,0296 | Finishing | RAL 9010 | (kein) | 1480 | 20 | 0 |
| 67 | 519AEC | 0,0592 | Primer | GW201 | (kein) | 1480 | 40 | 0 |
| 68 | 519AEC | 0,0592 | Primer | ZW-400 | (kein) | 1480 | 40 | 0 |

The desired result should look like this (values must be written into the same table **[3E_IDB_Aru].dbo.Material**):

| ID | P_GUID | Area | Group | Code | Variant | Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Dimension3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Extension | 27/1 ver | sj | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 55 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9005 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 56 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9010 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 57 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | GW201 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 110 |
| 58 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | ZW-400 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 110 |
| 59 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Extension | 27/1 ver | sj | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 60 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9005 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 61 | 519AEC | 0,0504 | Finishing | RAL 9010 | (kein) | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 62 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | GW201 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 50 |
| 63 | 519AEC | 0,1008 | Primer | ZW-400 | (kein) | 2520 | 40 | 50 |
| 64 | 519AEC | 0,0296 | Extension | 27/1 top | sj | 1480 | 20 | 110 |
| 65 | 519AEC | 0,0296 | Finishing | RAL 9005 | (kein) | 1480 | 20 | 110 |
| 66 | 519AEC | 0,0296 | Finishing | RAL 9010 | (kein) | 1480 | 20 | 110 |
| 67 | 519AEC | 0,0592 | Primer | GW201 | (kein) | 1480 | 40 | 110 |
| 68 | 519AEC | 0,0592 | Primer | ZW-400 | (kein) | 1480 | 40 | 110 |

Comment: Please use CTE (with clause) rather screenshots or plaintext tables to specify your input data. Or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific about the logic you want. And, please provide a sample of your desired result set based on the sample data you have shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**NOTE:** the code is run twice, because MaterialGroup 'Primer' Dimension2 value is double the value of MaterialGroup 'Extension' Dimension2 value. On the first pass 'null' values are being written into 'Primer' Dimension3 rows. The second pass will take care of this as I did not know how to nest this, if possible at all, into the first part of the code)
Here is the code I used to achieve the task:

```sql
PRINT '\tAdd Dimension3 values into Material table where Dimension3 = 0'
UPDATE t
SET Dimension3 = (
  SELECT Dimension3 FROM Material 
  WHERE
  Pos_GUID = t.Pos_GUID AND Dimension1 = t.Dimension1 AND Dimension2 = t.Dimension2 AND ID = (
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Material
    WHERE 
    Pos_GUID = t.Pos_GUID AND Dimension1 = t.Dimension1 AND Dimension2 = t.Dimension2 AND ID < t.ID AND Dimension3 > 0 ) 
)
FROM Material t
WHERE t.Dimension3 = 0

PRINT '\tAdd Dimension3 values into Material table where Dimension3 = null'
UPDATE t
SET Dimension3 = (
  SELECT Dimension3 FROM Material 
  WHERE
  Pos_GUID = t.Pos_GUID AND Dimension1 = t.Dimension1 AND Dimension2 * 2 = t.Dimension2 AND ID = (
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Material
    WHERE 
    Pos_GUID = t.Pos_GUID AND Dimension1 = t.Dimension1 AND Dimension2 * 2 = t.Dimension2 AND ID < t.ID AND Dimension3 > 0 ) 
)
FROM Material t
WHERE t.Dimension3 is NULL
```

[See the db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8070492b84e121932c25065b9c09a671)

Below is an example of the real database with some unnecessary columns removed. Here the Pos_GUID values are all mixed, but the ID numbers are always in ascending order under the same Pos_GUID:

| ID | Pos_GUID | MaterialGroup | Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Dimension3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 149 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 149 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Extension | 1500 | 18 | 89.5 |
| 150 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 150 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 1500 | 18 | 0 |
| 151 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 1500 | 18 | 0 |
| 152 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 551.67 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 152 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 1500 | 36 | 0 |
| 153 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 551.67 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 153 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 1500 | 36 | 0 |
| 154 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Extension | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 155 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 155 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 156 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 156 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 157 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 2520 | 40 | 0 |
| 158 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 2000 | 82 | 0 |
| 158 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 2520 | 40 | 0 |
| 159 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 2000 | 82 | 0 |
| 159 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Extension | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 160 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 2000 | 164 | 0 |
| 160 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 161 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 0 |
| 162 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 2000 | 82 | 0 |
| 162 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 2520 | 40 | 0 |

**Result:**

| ID | Pos_GUID | MaterialGroup | Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Dimension3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 149 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 149 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Extension | 1500 | 18 | 89.5 |
| 150 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 150 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 1500 | 18 | 89.5 |
| 151 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 1500 | 18 | 89.5 |
| 152 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 551.67 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 152 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 1500 | 36 | 89.5 |
| 153 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 551.67 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 153 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 1500 | 36 | 89.5 |
| 154 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Extension | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 155 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 155 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 156 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 1361 | 19.5 | 0 |
| 156 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 50 |
| 157 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 2520 | 40 | 50 |
| 158 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 2000 | 82 | 0 |
| 158 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 2520 | 40 | 50 |
| 159 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 2000 | 82 | 0 |
| 159 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Extension | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 160 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Primer | 2000 | 164 | 0 |
| 160 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 161 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Finishing | 2520 | 20 | 110 |
| 162 | 2E31E29F763844DA806B9868C403E219 | Finishing | 2000 | 82 | 0 |
| 162 | 519AEC1C7EB54C0B8DBC562A5194E38A | Primer | 2520 | 40 | 110 |

[See also this db<>fiddle with the actual database logic here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3123ce25150993716a0336dd630dc0ee)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UPDATE for this.

```sql
UPDATE Material
   SET Dim3 = Dimension3
 WHERE (MaterialGroup = 'Finishing' OR MaterialGroup = 'Primer')
   AND Dim3 IS NOT NULL
```

But you may want to leave your data unchanged and do this operation in your SELECT operations instead. This is especially true if you have a great many rows already.

```sql
SELECT ID, Fieldnumber, Area, MaterialGroup, Code, Variant, 
       Dimension1, Dimension2, Dimension3,
       CASE WHEN Dim3 IS NOT NULL            THEN Dim3
            WHEN MaterialGroup = 'Finishing' THEN Dimension3
            WHEN MaterialGroup = 'Primer'    THEN Dimension3
            ELSE                                  Dim3
       END AS Dim3
```

You might even create a view for this purpose if that makes sense in your application.

Answer (score 0):

use a cross apply between the source and target datasets.  the source data set uses a case when condition to find group equal to Primer and Finishing to move dimension3 into the dim3 column

```
declare @tmp as table(ID int,   P_GUID varchar(20), Area varchar(20),   [Group] varchar(20),    Code varchar(20),   Variant varchar(20), Dimension1 int, Dimension2 int, Dimension3 int,Dim3 int)

INSERT INTO @tmp(ID,P_GUID, Area,   [Group],    Code,   Variant,    Dimension1, Dimension2, Dimension3, Dim3)
values
 (54,'519AEC','0,0504','Extension','27/1 ver','sj',2520,20,110,NULL)
,(55,'519AEC','0,0504','Finishing','RAL 9005','(kein)',2520,20,0,NULL)
,(56,'519AEC','0,0504','Finishing','RAL 9010','(kein)',2520,20,0,NULL)
,(57,'519AEC','0,1008','Primer','GW201','(kein)',2520,40,0,NULL)
,(58,'519AEC','0,1008','Primer','ZW-400','(kein)',2520,40,0,NULL)
,(59,'519AEC','0,0504','Extension','27/1 ver','sj',2520,20,110,NULL)
,(60,'519AEC','0,0504','Finishing','RAL 9005','(kein)',2520,20,0,NULL)
,(61,'519AEC','0,0504','Finishing','RAL 9010','(kein)',2520,20,0,NULL)
,(62,'519AEC','0,1008','Primer','GW201','(kein)',2520,40,0,NULL)
,(63,'519AEC','0,1008','Primer','ZW-400','(kein)',2520,40,0,NULL)
,(64,'519AEC','0,0296','Extension','27/1 top','sj',1480,20,110,NULL)
,(65,'519AEC','0,0296','Finishing','RAL 9005','(kein)',1480,20,0,NULL)
,(66,'519AEC','0,0296','Finishing','RAL 9010','(kein)',1480,20,0,NULL)
,(67,'519AEC','0,0592','Primer','GW201','(kein)',1480,40,0,NULL)
,(68,'519AEC','0,0592','Primer','ZW-400','(kein)',1480,40,0,NULL)

update target
set
target.Dim3=source.Dim3
from @tmp as target
cross apply
(
select 
case when [Group] in('Finishing', 'Primer') then Dimension3 end Dim3
 from @tmp data
 where  target.ID=data.ID
 )source

 select * from @tmp
```

output

```
ID  P_GUID  Area    Group   Code    Variant Dimension1  Dimension2  Dimension3  Dim3
54  519AEC  0,0504  Extension   27/1 ver    sj  2520    20  110 NULL
55  519AEC  0,0504  Finishing   RAL 9005    (kein)  2520    20  0   0
56  519AEC  0,0504  Finishing   RAL 9010    (kein)  2520    20  0   0
57  519AEC  0,1008  Primer  GW201   (kein)  2520    40  0   0
58  519AEC  0,1008  Primer  ZW-400  (kein)  2520    40  0   0
59  519AEC  0,0504  Extension   27/1 ver    sj  2520    20  110 NULL
60  519AEC  0,0504  Finishing   RAL 9005    (kein)  2520    20  0   0
61  519AEC  0,0504  Finishing   RAL 9010    (kein)  2520    20  0   0
62  519AEC  0,1008  Primer  GW201   (kein)  2520    40  0   0
63  519AEC  0,1008  Primer  ZW-400  (kein)  2520    40  0   0
64  519AEC  0,0296  Extension   27/1 top    sj  1480    20  110 NULL
65  519AEC  0,0296  Finishing   RAL 9005    (kein)  1480    20  0   0
66  519AEC  0,0296  Finishing   RAL 9010    (kein)  1480    20  0   0
67  519AEC  0,0592  Primer  GW201   (kein)  1480    40  0   0
68  519AEC  0,0592  Primer  ZW-400  (kein)  1480    40  0   0
```